How to connect Flutter app to Node.js backend with MongoDB on localhost?
I'm trying to connect my Flutter app to a Node.js backend with MongoDB running on my local machine. In the backend, I'm using the following URL:
const MONGO_DB_CONFIG = {
    DB: "mongodb://localhost/ecommerce-app"
}

And in Postman, I can successfully access the backend API using http://localhost:4000/api/products/.
However, when I try to connect from my Flutter app using the following URL:
class Config {
  static const String apiURL = "10.0.2.2:4000";
}

I get the following error on the terminal:
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64...
Restarted application in 2,077ms.
I/.mongo_database(18019): NativeAlloc concurrent copying
 GC freed 56675(1921KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 2514KB/5029KB, paused 544us,73us total 273.631ms

======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following SocketException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 38912

How can I correctly configure the Flutter app to connect to the Node.js backend running on my local machine?

You forget the http://

Which platform are you testing? Is it Android, iOS, macOS, Windows, Linux, or Web?

Hello, I'm using Windows

change your code to
class Config {
    static const String apiURL = "http://10.0.2.2:4000";
}


Welcome to SO! Although this answer may fix the problem it lacks an explanation of why it works. For example, did you test it yourself? Have you stumbled upon the same situation? Please [edit] your answer and add the missing explanation. Better yet if a detailed one.
